# How do I return trigger error back to breezejs client side?

Tags: breeze

Validation can happen on client side and server side, what if it happens on db side, if I want to stop an insert/update by rollback in trigger, how do I notify the client side, now it seems breezejs just ignore my error raised in trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an Entity Framework or NHibernate backed server, then throwing any exception on the server should fail the entire transaction and turn into a failed save on the client ( with all changes placed back into their 'presave' state).  In order for this to occur the Breeze server must detect an exception.  You may need to have your trigger to raise an exception.

If you are using some other server, the behavior depends on whether the database supports tranactional semantics.  ( for example MongoDB does not).

Answer (score -1):

Found it does return, just need set severity  to higher and parse error message from http data.